# Inserting XML source to select using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML source that was created like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
<fnotes><option  value="">Select available time</option>
<option  value="0600">06:00 AM</option>
<option  value="0615">06:15 AM</option>
<option  value="0630">06:30 AM</option>
<option  value="0645">06:45 AM</option>
</fnotes>
</response>
```

Then my javascript looks like this:

```
var select = $('#sappttime');
$(xml).find('fnotes').each(function(){
var title = $(this).find('option').text();
select.append("<option/><option class='ddheader'>"+title+"</option>");
});
```

I want my select to have 4 values but it's returning as one complete value instead.  I was thinking of 2 solutions to populate the select base on the source xml. 1 is the example above, 2 adding the value on my select as is (don't know how to do that as well though). Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

So I have revised this to look like this:

```
var select = $('#sappttime');
$(xml).find('option').each(function(){
var title = $(this).find('option').text();
select.append("<option class='ddheader'>"+title);
```

It seems to loop into each record by value is being blank.  Basically variable title is returning as empty but iterates through each records.

Comment: remove <option/> start of text, you are appending

Comment: So i revised the javascript and added the new script on my original post.  It seems to work but having an empty values though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to find again. Try this:

```
var select = $('#sappttime');
$(xml).find('option').each(function(){
// $(this) in here is the option element
var title = $(this).text();
select.append("<option class='ddheader'>"+title);
```

Comment: Thank you. This perfectly works.  Just one more thing though, if I wanted to clear the content of the select element before appending.  It should be .remove() right?

Comment: I think you want `.empty()`.  `.remove()` removes the parent element as well. So in this case you'll want to do something like `select.empty()` first, before your xml operation.